# How to ensure that my WebRequest client does not stick to a specific server in a web farm?

Tags: azure, iis, httpwebrequest, load-balancing, azure-cloud-services

I have an OWIN API farm hosted by an Azure Worker Role.  It appears that requests to this role are not being round-robined properly.

Specifically, I have a decent number of C#-based agents whose requests seem to "stick" to an instance inside the role and not get round-robined. I suspect this is an issue on the client-side of those agents.  Since my agents are calling my Worker Role a couple of times every minute, this is a big problem.

Here's the code that calls my Worker Role (this is a GET method, there is a similar POST method).  Is there anything I can do to ensure that connections to specific instance do not stick?

```
var client = WebRequest.Create(url);
client.Headers.Add("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", token.AccessToken));
client.Headers.Add("AccountId", accountId.ToString());
client.Timeout = 120000;
client.Method = "GET";

using (var response = client.GetResponse())
{
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        if (stream == null) return default(T);

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            var data = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your load balancing mode : stickiness can be configured on 2-tuple (source, dest), 3-tuple (source, dest, port), or none/no stickiness which is equivalent to 5-tuple (source IP, source port, destination IP, destination port, protocol type). The default is none/5 tuple.

For a CloudService you can check/change the config is the .csdef file here is an example :

```
<Endpoints>
<InputEndpoint name="input-endpoint-name" loadBalancerProbe="load-balancer-probe-name" loadBalancerDistribution="sourceIP" protocol="[http|https|tcp|udp]" localPort="local-port-number" port="port-number" certificate="certificate-name" />
</Endpoints>
```

Here is the complete info : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-distribution-mode/

Comment: I'm using none/default
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="HttpsEndpoint" protocol="https" port="443" certificate="SSL" localPort="443" />
    </Endpoints>

Answer (score 0):

Azure Websites have a feature called Application Request Routing (ARR) affinity that makes sessions sticky between the client and the instance of the website it connects to by providing the client with a cookie that encodes identification for that website instance. All subsequent requests from the client are guided to that original website instance.

ARR can sometimes be useful but introduces "statefulness" and limits the scalability of the system because clients get attached to a particular website instance. This is especially problematic if the instance the client originally connected to has failed!

It is possible to disable ARR for Websites by modifying web.config to send an Arr-Disable-Session-Affinity custom header:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Arr-Disable-Session-Affinity" value="True" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Not using Websites, but using a Worker Role

Comment: I haven't tried this with web roles, but since web roles use IIS, you might want to try it anyway and modify the web.config file.  I wouldn't be surprised if it worked.  Please let me know, I'm curious to find out.

Comment: yeah, as I mentioned, not running Web Roles, the Web Api is a OWIN-based, running outside of IIS in a Worker ROle

Comment: Then, whatever server you are using, try adding the **Arr-Disable-Session-Affinity** header with a value of **true** to your calls.

If that doesn't work, paste a capture of one of your GET's (including headers) and I'll try to figure it out.